# ESP8266 : WPA ENTERPRISE LOGIN WITHOUT CA CERTIFICATE

Tags: arduino, iot, esp8266

Thanks a lot for giving your time and reading this,

I have gone though the WPA enterprise question posted in the ESP8266 forum and the related links, but it's not able to help me so I'm starting another topic.

I am trying to connect my ESP to my office network.
To connect through mobile this is usually is the setting:

1. SSID:PanLAN
2. EAP methode : PEAP
3. Phase 2 authentication: None
4. Ca Certificate: None
5. Identity: Asia-Pacific\SLAIK
6. password: Badonkadong

I took the edurom.ino from joostd's github and tried to run it.
https://github.com/genomics-admin/esp8266-eduroam/tree/master/Arduino
I got the following error.

```
    error: 'wifi_station_set_username' was not declared in this scope

   wifi_station_set_username(identity, sizeof(identity));

                                                       ^

ESP8266_PEAPAuth:323: error: 'wifi_station_set_cert_key' was not declared in this scope

   if( wifi_station_set_cert_key(testuser_cert_pem, testuser_cert_pem_len, testuser_key_pem, testuser_key_pem_len, NULL, 0) == 0 ) {

                                                                                                                          ^

ESP8266_PEAPAuth:337: error: 'wifi_station_clear_cert_key' was not declared in this scope

   wifi_station_clear_cert_key();

                               ^

ESP8266_PEAPAuth:338: error: 'wifi_station_clear_username' was not declared in this scope

   wifi_station_clear_username();

                               ^
exit status 1
'wifi_station_set_username' was not declared in this scope.
```

I'm new to ESP/Arduino however to my eyes it looks like i'm missing the user_interface.h and c_type.h file.

1. The github account don't have them, so where can I get
   them from?
2. I know user_interface.h is available on github
   from other projects, but can I use them?
3. If yes, then
   where shall I put the user_interface.h after downloading?
4. I found ctype.h in my computer @ "C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include" is it the same as
   c_type.h mentioned in the code? can I rename and use ctype.h?
5. Is there any other/better example available for me to
   follow and get my ESP connected to the network?

Comment: Do you use https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino ?

Comment: Yes I have, However I couldn't find any particulate example that helps me with WPA login without CA certificate. Kindly let me know if there's one hiding in that git and I will re-look into it. Thank you.

Comment: It's in It's in ~/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.1.0/tools/sdk/include/user_interface.h on my mac.